# Is there any advantage to catch big fish?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm usually spending half of my days fishing to get a little income every day while my crops are growing. I just realized that, as I'm fishing, I'm catching bigger and bigger fish and that I'm most of the time getting at least a silver star on each fish.

So, is there any difference between little fish and big fish? Are big fish more likely to be high quality?

Comment: I'm not sure enough of this to post an answer, but I believe fish size is loosely correlated to quality, but irrelevant to anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quality is determined by your Fishing Level and how far away from land you cast your rod, up to 6 tiles at 'MAX' throw.

At level 10 Fishing, if you cast into the Ocean with a MAX throw, you are guaranteed to get a Gold quality fish if don't get trash.

Size has no influence on the quality of the fish.

Comment: In all my time playing, the size of a fish doesn't seem to influence anything, though [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/258039/163757) says otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, the quality of the fish affects the size, not the other way around.